# "is-related-to"column with n>1 entries, n can change dynamically: Other solution than list?

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio

I develop a Software for managing documents. In this software I want to show dependencies between the documents: "In order to finish DocumentA, you first need to finish DocumentB".

I want to use a SQL-Database, IDE is VS2013-Ultimate.

The Problem now is that I don't know how to represent the dependencies in the database:

**Document(PK).............Needs**

Doc A...........................Doc B, Doc C

Doc C...........................Doc E

Should the column "Needs" contain lists or should I create a new table for every group there is? In the example above this would be:

Table1:

**Document(PK).............Needs**

Doc A...........................Group1

Doc C...........................Doc E

Table2:

**Name(PK)............Name1.............Name2**

Group1.................Doc B................Doc C

And then how would I implement this? I thought of doing the dependency calculation within the program and then sending out single SQL-Queries as the calculation is ready.

Short summary: 
 **1. Is creating many small tables for groups the correct approach?**

**2. What would be a good way to implement this?**

Thank you for your time and attention,
Regards, PlankaForest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go for table `document_relations` which has columns:

- document1 id
- document2 id
- relation type

Then insert things like

```
| doc A | doc B | requires |
| doc A | doc C | requires |
| doc C | doc E | requires |
```

Depending on your use case, there could be a unique constraint on doc1+doc2.

Comment: This sounds like the solution, will give it a try. Also easy to implement, thank you! :)

Edit: Yep, Unique-constraint would be very good in order to avoid "A needs B, B needs A"-looks

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with one table that lists all of the documents each document needs, then you can check them in a recursive fashion

```
Document | DependsOn
DocA     | DocC
DocA     | DocC
DocC     | DocE
```